# How can I resolve rotating 90 degree of video when playing on android?

Tags: android, video, surfaceview

I have a video recorder on my android app which works well. Most important piece of code is here:

```
protected void startRecording() throws IOException 
{

 mCamera.stopPreview();
 mCamera.unlock();
 mrec = new MediaRecorder();  
 mrec.setCamera(mCamera);   
 mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
 mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
 mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
 mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);
 mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
 mrec.prepare();
 isRecording=true;
 mrec.start();
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
protected void stopRecording() 
{

    releaseOnExit();
     mCamera = Camera.open();
     mCamera.lock();  
     surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
     surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
     surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
     surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

     Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try {
        mCamera .setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera .startPreview();
    btnlistToggle.setEnabled(true);
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{

     if (mCamera != null)
       {
          Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
          mCamera.setParameters(params);
          mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
          try {
            mCamera .setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } 
          catch (IOException e) 
          {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          mCamera .startPreview();

       }
       else
       {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         VideoRecorderActivity.this.finish();
       }


}
```

I have a video player on my app ,too. But when I play my recorded videos , video 90 degree rotates which isn't good for showing. I play my recorded video by KMplayer on windows But video has 90 degree rotation at there . And I must tell that I use `SurfaceView` for player. How can I resolve it?
It is necessary for me or for other users read this post.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20748843/2556111

Comment: @ramaral how can i get cameraId? there isnt no method for cameraId . I read your answer in this link but when i must call method with context and cameraId I cant acces cameraId and I even dont know what is cameraId.is it mCamera? I use mCamera but give syntax error. because it isnt id surely.please help.

Answer (score 4):

Preview orientation depends on the orientation of the device and camera orientation.

Basically what you need is to calculate the orientation of the camera preview based on those conditions.

We need two help methods:

1 - Calculate the device orientation:

```
public int getDeviceOrientation(Context context) {

    int degrees = 0;
    WindowManager windowManager =
            (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();

    switch(rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    return degrees;
}
```

2 - Calculate Camera preview rotation:

```
public static int getPreviewOrientation(Context context, int cameraId) {

   int temp = 0;
   int previewOrientation = 0;

   Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
   Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);

   int deviceOrientation = getDeviceOrientation(context);
   temp = cameraInfo.orientation - deviceOrientation + 360;
   previewOrientation = temp % 360;

    return previewOrientation;
}
```

At your code, before mediaRecorder.prepare();

```
int rotation = getPreviewOrientation(context, cameraId);
mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation);
```

To use those methods is required a context and the camera Id in use.

Get the camera Id for back camera:

```
public int getCamaraBackId(){

    numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1 // Device do not have back camera !!!!???
}
```

Open camera with `Camera.open(getCamaraBackId());`

For more information see [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

Comment: this not worked for me. no effect on rotating at all.what do i do now?

Comment: Have set rotation to `mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation);` or to `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);`?

Comment: I have mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation)  and mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90) at same time. of cource I remove  mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90) and write mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation)  only, but it not worked .

Comment: Please try a third possibility: only mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(rotation);

Comment: this way not worked too.I read documentation about setOrientationHint(int degree)which is : Sets the orientation hint for output video playback. This method should be called before prepare().This method will not trigger the source video frame to rotate during video recording, but to add a composition matrix containing the rotation angle in the output video if the output format is OutputFormat.THREE_GPP or OutputFormat.MPEG_4 so that a video player can choose the proper orientation for playback. Note that some video players may choose to ignore the compostion matrix in a video during playback.

Comment: may be my problem is some things like this sentense:Note that some video players may choose to ignore the compostion matrix in a video during playback.  I really dont know what is problem and solving.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. If video player ignore the composition matrix, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: can i use video editor for rotating? do you know about that? how?

Comment: You can use Windows Movie Maker.

Comment: This answer should be framed, I wasted hours trying to figure out the stupid orientation of the preview and the recorded video. Samsung S3 would show the recording in portrait mode, and Nexus 7 would have it upside down. Thanks for sharing @ramaral, the 2 functions (`getDeviceOrientation` and `getPreviewOrientation`) work perfectly for me (delete the `static` modifier though for `getPreviewOrientation`)!

Answer (score 1):

I know your issue,

Video use `Media Recorder` from `Camera`, so you need `rotate Media Recorder`. use below codes should be fixed your issue.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param mMediaRecorder
 * @return
 */
public static MediaRecorder rotateBackVideo(MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder) {
    /**
     * Define Orientation of video in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    switch (CustomCamera.current_orientation) {
        case 0:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
            break;
        case 90:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(180);
            break;
        case 180:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
            break;
        case 270:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(0);
            break;
    }

    return mMediaRecorder;
}
```

Should add before `prepare()` method :

```
// Step 5: Set the preview output
    /**
     * Define Orientation of image in here,
     * if in portrait mode, use value = 90,
     * if in landscape mode, use value = 0
     */
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder = Utils.rotateBackVideo(CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder);
    CustomCamera.mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
```

Thank you

Comment: This is more correct. The other method just keeps the rotation stable. At least one my device.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your MediaRecorder.

```
   mrec.setOrientationHint(90);
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);
mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
mrec.setOrientationHint(90);
mrec.prepare();
```